# How to call MySQL Function within the Query, so that query can use the session variable set in the function?

Tags: mysql, view, parameters

```
SELECT s.* FROM (SELECT setUserId('abcd123') p) tmp_p, main_article_view s
```

The problem is that the function `setUserId(userId char(36))` in MySQL set a session variable, that is being used in `main_article_view;` the first time I run this query, it does not work, because the function gets executed in the end.

But when I run it second time, it does works perfectly; because was set previously on first run in session.

The limitation for me is that I cannot use the simple `:=` operator to set the `userIdParam` (session variable) in NHibernate; because NHibernate uses `:` for named parameters.

The below query works, but it is not working as I said with NHibernate.

```
SELECT s.* FROM (SELECT @userIdParam:='abc123' p) tmp_param, main_article_view s
```

The workaround I am doing right-now is calling first the function `setUserId()` and then calling the actual query alone like `select * from main_article_view`, which works, but then there will be two calls, which I don't like.

Actually I just want to use View with parameter; so any suggestions would be welcomed?

Thanks & Regards